# не могу в тег select написать option в котором была бы картинка

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, vue.js

дорогие разработчики, мне необходимо создать список в котором можно было бы поместить картинку. Прошу,обьясните понятным языком.
вот моя разметка -

```
<div class="country-inner">
            <p class="column-form_description">Страна*</p>
            <label for="country"></label>
            <select class="country-select" id="country" >
            
            </select>
            <input type="number" class="column-form_item" placeholder="Россия" v-model.trim = "numberPhone">
        </div>
```

Comment: В штатный select option вставить картинку нельзя. Вы можете нагуглить решения (например: https://codepen.io/antonandoff/pen/PmQvBz) или попытаться написать самостоятельно: суть в том, чтобы с помощью div'ов или ul li сымитировать функционал select option. И, разумеется, без js/jquery не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так

```
  <select>
      <option style="background-image:url(country1.png);">country1</option>
      <option style="background-image:url(country2.png);">country2</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: а Вы хоть потестили это решение, прежде чем давать ответ?

Comment: нет, не получилось..